# How to improve IF NOT NULL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `title_mediaasset` 
  WHERE upload_id is not null 
  ORDER BY `upload_date` DESC
```

It takes almost a second and doesn't use an index:

```
id  select_type      table              type    possible_keys           key     key_len  ref    rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE           title_mediaasset   ALL     upload_id,upload_id_2   NULL    NULL    NULL    119216  Using where; Using filesort
```

How can I improve this query?

This table holds about 100k results, and will probably increase to 1M in the next year.

Comment: You can `USE INDEX` or add a clause `AND upload_id > 0`.  See if any of those help.

Comment: Would an index actually help? How many rows have a null `upload_id`?

Comment: @PeteGO `upload_id > 0` is *very* different from `upload_id is not null`.

Comment: `using filesort` can mean that the result set is too large to fit in memory to be sorted in one go. Is this a very large table? If so, are you able to increase the amount of memory in your server?

Comment: 1s for a query that potentially returns 100k results sounds like reasonable performance.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I know it is, but I've found that when a key exists and isn't used, adding a clause like this "helps" it work out a better plan where it actually uses the index.  I was assuming all ids are greater than 0 though - should've mentioned that.

Comment: please show us DESCRIBE and SHOW INDEX for this table, what are upload_id,upload_id_2 indexes put on?

Comment: @Blogbeard - just curious, how wouldn't an index help?

Comment: Do you need all the results?  Often adding a `limit` clause also encourages index usage for `order by`.

Comment: @PeteGO well if there are only a few records with upload_id being null, pretty much every row will need to be retrieved and sorted anyway.

Comment: @PeteGO @Blorgbeard Not only retrieved but it would first read the index and then additionally read "most" rows, this can be more work than directly reading all (depending on the amount of NULL values). If not using `SELECT *` but just "a few" fields a covering index, on the other hand, might allow to read everything from index.

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid nulls in your database for a ton of reasons. For the columns that would commonly contain null values, consider changing them to a boolean or smallint type (or whatever type is actually supposed to be in there). And run update statements on your tables to change the values from `null` to something meaningful, like 0 or false. This way, you would actually be able to take advantage of indexing and not have as dirty data. I know this isn't answering your question, it's just some advice

Comment: btw. if you only need the top results or such and add a `LIMIT` clause and updae to MySQL 5.6 you will see a big improvement

Comment: People are obssessed about the NULL being an issue. Its not the main cause of the problem.  The 1 second duration is almost certainly down to not having an index on upload_date, you can see this from the execution plan since its doing a file sort.   Add an index on (upload_id, upload_date) and also a LIMIT as johannes says, Im sure it will be fine

Answer (score 2):

If you need all rows and all columns from the result, you can't re-write the query to make it better. It is probably running slow because you don't have an index on `upload_date`.

If you don't need all of the rows, use `LIMIT` and you'll see a decent speed increase on the `ORDER BY`.

If you don't need all of the columns, use `SELECT [columns you need]` instead of `SELECT *`. That way if you *really* need to optimize the query, you can put the columns you need in your index so that you can read everything directly from the index: `index on (upload_id, upload_date, [other columns in select statement])`.

If you need all of the columns, or a good number of them, just add `index on (upload_id, upload_date)`.